# Python pip install error 1 when trying to install any package

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am using Python 2.7.13 on Windows with Administrator rights.  I am trying to install packages using pip and for any package that I try to install I am getting the following output:

```
Collecting os
  Using cached os-0.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\name\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-csfxlg\\os\\setup.py'

----------------------------------------


Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
c:\users\name\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-csfxlg\os\
```

The output from echo %PATH% is:

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
```

I've upgraded my setuptools, and also read the other overflow discussions with this issue and have yet to resolve it.

If I try to install another package, I get the following error:

```
 >pip install time
 Collecting time
   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time (from versions: )
 No matching distribution found for time
```

Comment: `time` and `os` are stdlib modules, not pypi packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anthony mentions, [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) and [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) are part of the Python standard library. You will not need to install these using `pip`. To use them in a Python program:

```
import time
import os
```